# Cloud Function keeps running

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

We have a Firebase function which removes items after 24 hours. The function works, however, the web page linking to the function keeps running so I guess the function is in an endless loop. Is there any way to fix this issue?

This is our function:

```
exports.delete = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
const dayAgo = currentTime - 86400000;

ref.child('testlijst')
    .orderByChild('tijd')
    .endAt(dayAgo)
    .once('value')
    .then(snap => {
       snap.forEach(c => {
          c.ref.remove();
       })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are required to send a response to the client in order to terminate an HTTPS type function without timing out.  You should do that only after the work you're doing in the function is complete.  This means you'll need to learn how to use promises.

You will need to collect all the promises returned by c.ref.remove() and wait for all of them to complete before terminating the function with a response to the client:

```
ref.child('testlijst')
    .orderByChild('tijd')
    .endAt(dayAgo)
    .once('value')
    .then(snap => {
        const promises = [];
        snap.forEach(c => {
           const p = c.ref.remove();
           promises.push(p);
        })
        Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
            res.send("done");
        });
    });
});
```